# unable to install universal windows tools and windows 8.1 tools in vs 2015

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have tried reinstalling. Even tried installing by click on missing universal windows tools. The installer pops up lets me to select windows8.0/8.1 and universal windows tools, it says finished successfully but again the same missing universal windows tools and missing windows 8.0/8.1 tools..

Comment: Have you enabled hyper-v? It is required for emulators. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: It matters which version of Windows you are on. If you are on Windows 7 these tools won't appear. Are you on Windows 10?